# SQL: aggregating pairs without JOIN (challenging)

Tags: mysql, sql

Could you please help me with a very difficult question?

I have a table 'itemslog' in MySQL DBMS with two columns: 'userid' and 'itemid', looks like:

```
| user1 | item 1 |
| user1 | item 2 |
| user2 | item 1 |
| user2 | item 2 |
| user2 | item 3 |
```

I need to count how much users have every pair of item, i.g. answer like that:

```
| item1 | item2 | 2 |
| item1 | item3 | 1 |
| item2 | item3 | 1 |
```

Usually we can use query based on JOIN operations, like that:

```
SELECT
    t1.itemname,
    t2.itemname,
    count(*)
FROM
    itemslog AS t1
    CROSS JOIN itemslog AS t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
WHERE
    t1.itemname < t2.itemname
GROUP BY
    t1.itemname, t2.itemname;
```

But it takes a lot of computations and in my situation it is useless (i have about 200k rows). Can you give me an advice, is there another ways to do that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are trying to count here.  Do you want to see if a given user has certain items?  Or something else?

Comment: Do you have another table `items` in which `itemid` is the primary key -- a reference table?

Comment: Every user could carry any amount of items. For every pair of item i want to count amount of users who carry it both. In example pair item1 & item2 carry two users, and pair item1&item3 - only one.

Comment: No, I don't have reference table. But it is not a problem in my situation to build it, if it helps.

Comment: You should tag which DBMS implementation you're using.....

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It is MySQL.

Comment: You are joining same tables and pulling same column. It will provide you same result in both the columns

Comment: I've made little note - it is CROSS JOIN, which give us cartesian multiplication, from which we takes results that match our conditions. It works, but only for small tables.

Comment: Why is your query useless? If I understand your question correctly, your query is fine, and a `cross join` is the same as a normal `join` if you use `on`. You might need `count(distinct t1.userid)` if your rows are not unique. But since you want to combine all items with all items, you have to combine all items with all items, so this is the way to go (unless you have special data distribution, e.g. just 3 items in 200k rows). And 200k rows is not much - unless you don't have an index. Use the index `userid, itemname` and test again. (It will be faster if they are integers, not `varchar`).

Comment: Thank you a lot, guys! I get the point. Should dig in using indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT t1.itemname, t2.itemname, count(*)
FROM itemslog t1 JOIN
     itemslog t2
     ON t1.userid = t2.userid AND t1.itemname < t2.itemname
GROUP BY t1.itemname, t2.itemname;
```

For this query you want an index on `itemslog(userid, itemname)`:

```
create index itemslog_userid_itemname on itemslog(userid, itemname);
```

Assuming you have only a handful of items for each `userid`, this should have reasonable performance.

Comment: WHOA!! It is look like a freakin' miracle!)  It works! I should better dig in understanding working with index. Thank you a lot, man!